# Font Apply issue on fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have created canvas where user can add text and change the font style. Its working fine if you apply font style for one particular text/Object.

## Code

https://codepen.io/dhavalsisodiya/pen/OQEzVE

Code to change the font style

```
$("#font_change").change(function(){
    var font_style = $(this).val();
    if(font_style=='')
    {
        alert('Please select a Font Style');
        return false;
    }
    var tObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    //Check that text is selected
    if(tObj==undefined)
    {
        alert('Please select a Text');
        return false;
    }
    tObj.set({
        fontFamily: font_style
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

To reproduce the issue, please follow below:

1. Add Text using "Add Text" button
2. Now change the font style    (i.e. select Comic Sans)
3. Now drag that text to some where else
4. Add other text using "Add Text" button
5. Apply font style (i.e.select Garamond)
6. Copy/cut that text from canvas
7. Go to first  added text(step 1, click on that text) and place the
   copied text there
8. Now above 2 text merged into one, so now change the font
       style (i.e. courier new)

Now you can see that font style is only applying to first text which we have added using step 1, not for other text which we have later merged into first text (please check below ss).
[image]

So how to resolve that issue?

Note: Fabric version 2.0.0-beta.7

Comment: This is because its storing the previous styles, if you don't want you can remove the styles for letters. Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/YevOKQ) (line76)

Comment: @Durga, that's the answer. Thanks a lot. You should post it as answer.

Comment: I am removing the styles of whole text object.

Comment: Is there a way to just remove fontFamily?

Comment: Loop through the styles array and remove font family, before it was removing all the styles from copied text, in new version its storing, don't know exactly

Comment: thanks for the detail. As of now removing the styles of whole text object is fine for me.